# php -v and php-config --version are different

Tags: php

I get 2 diffrent Output for php version using these 2 commands

when i run `php -v`

```
PHP 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.4 (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 19:37:11) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
```

However on Running `php-config --version` i get

```
5.3.10-1ubuntu3.19
```

I want my php-config to show the correct version of php i.e 5.4. Please tell me how i can configure this.

Output of 
`which  php` is 
    `/usr/bin/php`

and

`which php-config` is 
    `/usr/bin/php-config`

Comment: How did you install your PHP? Sounds like you have a partially overwritten installation with mixed up php and php-config binaries.

Comment: Yes this may be a problem, can i fix it without having to reinstall php ?

Comment: That depends. In the end everything is just files on disk, so if you arrange your files correctly, you can fix the problem. Of course, nobody here can tell you exactly how to do that with the little bit of information given. Reinstalling is the best method unless you know exactly what you're doing.